# Thunderbird on Ubuntu 20.04.1 stop or take control of updates

Tags: updates, 20.04, thunderbird

I was here a while back asking how to get Thunderbird on Ubuntu and Windows 7 to share a profile on a common mount point on a non-system disk.  I had it working once, but Ubuntu keeps messing with the Thunderbird version, destroying my hard-won compatibility. One must have the identical versions on both platforms.  I was finally able to download version 78 for Windows after a lot of searching.  On the Ubuntu side, I am on the security PPA, which gave me version 78 when I upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04.

Now that I have the same Thunderbird versions on both platforms, I can finally share a profile again.  However, I do not want an Ubuntu update to break the setup any more. Is there a way to stop Ubuntu updates from touching Thunderbird while allowing all other updates?  I can stifle Thunderbird updates on Windows easily, so if I can do the same on Ubuntu, maybe I can have stability and functionality for more than a week.

The ultimate objective is completely seamless toggling between the two platforms.  Easlly done with Firefox, Libre Office, and UltraEdit, but nearly impossible with Thunderbird.

Comment: The Ubuntu repository -security pocket is not a PPA.

Comment: ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa

Comment: Says right on that PPA's [description](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) that it is not for general use: "*Unless you are testing updates, you should NOT install packages from this PPA.*" Fully tested security updates for Thunderbird and Firefox are released regularly through the -security pocket (not the PPA). Future readers of this question should NOT add the PPA.

Comment: Yeahbut, it's the only way to get the Thunderbird version which is current on Windows.  If the versions don't match exactly, your profile is destroyed by using the "wrong" one.  It is the only cross-platform tool I use which is this nasty.  I would consider some other cross-platform email client, but I can't find one.

Comment: Hence directing that comment to "Future readers," not to you. Use of the *same* profile by multiple OS is not an expected use case, which is why your pants are getting shredded in the gears. File a bug with Mozilla to include your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way:

```
sudo apt-mark hold thunderbird
sudo apt-mark unhold thunderbird   // For manual upgrades. Afterward, re-apply the hold
```

WARNING: Delaying security upgrades, while convenient, may incur risk. Do not neglect to check for and apply upgrades regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I also find this Thunderbird incompatibility between versions annoying.  Logging this with Mozilla I asked if at least compatibility could be retained between say all subversions of say Thunderbird 68.x.x but got the reply that this is not considered important.  I have found this to have occurred only in the past couple of years.  The answer seems to be carefully to manually synchronise updates in Windows and Ubuntu.  I might look to see if another flavour of Linux does this better.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I, too, posted the question onthe Mozilla support site and got no response at all.  Verifies the perceived unimportance at Mozilla.